# Square-Cube Law?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, dimensional-analysis

I've heard about something called the [square-cube law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-cube_law). What is it? All I know of it is that it has something to do with mass of large objects and their gravitational influence.

Comment: This is explained on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-cube_law). Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72641/2451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably referring to Kepler's third law, which states that the square of the period of orbit of a planet is proportional to the cube of the semi-major axis of its orbit. It can be mathematically expressed as 
$$ \frac{T_1^2}{R_1^3}\approx\frac{T_2^2}{R_2^3}$$
for planets $1$ and $2$ in the solar system. This equality is exact in the limit where the mass of the Sun goes to infinity.