Why do most fish wiggle their tails side to side, and not up-down?
Is moving a vertical fin side to side more efficient than moving a horizontal fin up and down in water for fish locomotion? The answer might lie in how fish propel themselves using vortices, but I don't know the details.
Context: I wondered why most fish evolved to wiggle their tails side to side instead of up and down. If the ocean is an isotropic environment, I wouldn't expect any preference for any particular direction.
Could there be a physical reason?

I think there is more physics than biology in my question.  Similar questions have been asked before, and the tag Biophysics exists. How can ants carry items much heavier than themselves? . Does physics explain why the laws and behaviors observed in biology are as they are?

I don't know that this is really a physics question since there exist plenty of aquatic life that does it the other way. But I'd be surprised if someone knows the reason.

Fish tails have vertical fins. Wiggling them up and down would have much less effect than wiggling them side to side. Whales, on the other hand, all have horizontal fins on their tails, and whales wiggle their tails up and down. (And, if anybody's wondering about pinnipeds, they don't swim with their tiny little tails. The "fins" on the back end of a pinniped's body are their feet.)

@SolomonSlow my question then would be why it has to be like that in the first place. Why the horizontal fin in the first place. yeah whales dolphins and all mammals are exceptions, which is why I told "most" fish.

@Triatticus yes, but I believe most things in biology have evolved, to reach some configuration which may be explained with physical reason s.

If you asked why it must be that way, my comment suggests that it does not have to be that way. Fish wag their tails side-to-side, whales wag their tails up-and-down. Both of them have survived to the present day, and if it weren't for humans hunting them and messing with their environment, neither group would be in any danger of extinction at this point in time.

@SolomonSlow No, I asked why it is mostly that way. There are a lot of exceptions.

Sure, whatever. The fact is, some aquatic animals are doing just fine with tails that move side-to-side, and some others are doing just fine with tails that move up-and-down. So, it seems to me, that ought to prove that there is no physical reason why it must be one or the other. Both strategies work. It's all just accidents of evolution.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question about physics.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Could it be for propulsion?

A little physical insight on swimming fish: “How do fish swim so quickly?”. The OP appeals for a physical explanation not an evolutionary one, so I think that it is relevant for this site.

In side to side wiggles, the tail doesn't fight the force of gravity.

This is a good question in my opinion, but I think it would be better answered at biology stack exchange (https://biology.stackexchange.com/). Also voting to close since it's more of a biology question than a physics question. Though of course physics will play into the answer.

I think there is a valid physics (fluid mechanics) question in whether side-to-side motion of a vertically-oriented tail has some kind of advantage in propulsion over up-and-down motion of a horizontally-oriented tail, when paired with the rest of the body of a typical fish, which is typically more "tall" than "wide".

This is an interdisciplinary biophysics question that I am voting to reopen.  Although closely related questions have been asked on Biology SE, i.e. "Best tail for swimming?" and "Why is there a difference in the rotation of the tail fin in fish compared to marine mammals?", the physics question - is there any difference in propulsion efficiency for horizontal or vertical tails - is not answered there.  Note that the answer may differ when swimming near or far below the surface.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a question of evolutionary biology and ought to be asked on [biology.se]

The physics part of the question is essentially "their bones are lined up for side-to-side propulsion" but OPs real question is "why fish have their bones lined up that way" which isn't physics at all

@KyleKanos All I am asking is, whether moving a vertical fin side to side more efficient than moving a horizontal fin up and down in water for fish propulsion, in terms of the fluid dynamics involved. I don't think that's a biology question, nor would I get a good answer from their forums.

I have made an edit that emphasizes that this is a physics question and voted to reopen.  I could have eliminated all reference to fish or cetaceans to make it a "pure" physics question, but that would not reflect AlphaLife's inspiration for the question. Biophysics is an important branch of physics present in many, many university physics departments.

@DavidBailey that is what I could call a radical edit that changes the question asked so wildly that the two posted answers are, in large part, now invalid because they address other aspects that you have removed. Thus, I am rolling the change back to what OP asked.

@DavidBailey Agree. This is one aspect here in this community I don't like. I feel people tend to get too stringent in the details, that they forget the essence of a question.

As far as I am concerned, I am curious about a phenomenon and I want to seek the answer. Why should all these details, matter more than answering the question? I may be misunderstanding; I am sorry if my question was not clear; but I think I have made what I want clear through the edits and comments.

...and I want to seek the answer." OK, so seek the answer elsewhere. Is that a problem? You want to ask us the best way to fill out your tax forms here too?

It is hubris to think that all question can be answered by "physics." I am not suggesting hubris on the part of OP. I am just suggesting that other divisions of science exist for a reason and should not be thought of as secondary or as ultimately deriving their validity from physics. It is OK to ask a biologist.

@hft Sure, I don't have any problem posting in bio SE. But I want to know what rule I am violating here. I think there is more physics than biology in my question.  Similar questions have been asked before, and the tag Biophysics exists. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153538/how-can-ants-carry-items-much-heavier-than-themselves . https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/625503/does-physics-explain-why-the-laws-and-behaviors-observed-in-biology-are-as-they

I don't know what rule you are violating. You might be able to figure it out by reading this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

(Anyways, the question seems to have been reopened and I didn't vote to close it.)

It is unclear to me if you are asking about the tail motion in relation to gravity, or in relation to the shape/orientation of the rest of the fish's body, or both. (1) How do you define "up" (i.e. the $+y$ direction)? Is it defined as $-\vec g$, or in relation to the fish's body? E.g. which way would you characterize the tail motion of a halibut? (2) Are we considering the shape of the fish's body (which way it is "flattened") or can it be assumed cylindrically symmetric about the "spine"? If it's the latter, it would appear you are asking only about the tail motion with respect to gravity.

@Puk Up is the direction against gravity. The coordinate system is defined with the positive y axis pointing against gravity.

@Puk the tail motion with respect to gravity. The shape of body is irrelevant.

I cannot think of any physical reason. And given the fact that aquatic animals that swim with horizontal tails that flap up and down (dolphins and whales) also exist, I would assume that neither has any significant physical advantage.

for those voting to close this question, a question about whether it is more efficient to propel an object with a with a side to side motion of a tail rather than an up down motion is about physics, not evolution. The assumption that organisms would generally evolve to the most efficient solution is  a trivial conclusion from biology and this question does not involve biology beyond that assumption.

@KDP "The assumption that organisms would generally evolve to the most efficient solution is a trivial conclusion from biology" Not "most efficient", but at least most advantageous to survivability and reproduction in the given environment of the organsim.

As suggested in the question, symmetry tells us that the caudal (tail) fin of a balanced, neutrally buoyant, underwater animal or vehicle in an isotropic unbounded aquatic environment should work equally well at any angle.  This is why studies of hydrodynamical caudal fin efficiency or the fluid mechanics of oscillatory swimming can ignore the orientation of the fin.
This isotropy argument fails, however, if the symmetry is broken because of, for example:

a preferred (typically horizontal) plane of movement,
deviations from neutral buoyancy,
proximity to a water-air or water-bottom interface.

In such cases it may be advantageous to have better manoeuvrability in a particular plane. Caudal fins are more effective in driving acceleration in directions at right angles to the orientation of the tail, so a caudal fin orientation perpendicular to the preferred plane of movement would usually be more effective.
Vertical tails improve horizontal manoeuvrability
As noted in @Andrew-Steane's answer, fish often prefer to move in horizontal layers of water with specific salinity, temperature, and light levels, or distance from the surface or bottom.
A horizontally flexible body with a strong vertical tail exerts its forces in the horizontal plane and hence can drive horizontal changes in direction (yaw), maximizing manoeuvrability in the preferred horizontal plane.
If, has been argued, fish first evolved in shallow intertidal-subtidal environments, it is possible that horizontal mobility and hence vertical tails gave an evolutionary advantage.
Horizontal tails provide more direct control of horizontal trim
Deviations from neutral buoyancy require corrections from horizontal (or at least non-vertical) control surfaces to correct ("trim") undesired deviations from horizontal motion.
Aquatic animals are generally close enough to neutral buoyancy to be easily trimmed by relatively small ancillary control surfaces (e.g. pectoral fins) and body shape, but one advantage of horizontal caudal fins is that they can provide both propulsion and horizontal trim control.
Most independently evolved aquatic thunniform animals such as sharks, tuna, and ichthyosaurs, all have (or in the last case had) vertical caudal fins and pelvic fins to help control trim.  Extra fins increase drag, however. With horizontal caudal fins, evolving dolphins did not need their hind pelvic limbs/flukes for trim control and have completely lost them, reducing drag.
Horizontal tails improve vertical manoeuvrability
In contrast to fish, aquatic mammals need to breathe air so they are frequently moving vertically up to and down from the water surface, so their horizontal tail is well matched since it is optimal for driving changes in vertical (pitch).  This can be particularly helpful when they are moving long distances at speed and need to breathe frequently. Simply swimming on the surface is less efficient because of surface-wave drag, so fast moving aquatic mammals typically swim below the surface coming up briefly for air, or engage in energy-saving porpoising where they spend a significant fraction of their time out of the water completely.  Such movements are easier with their horizontal tail.
Biological evidence that horizontal fins are not better
Finally, it is fun to note that there is a strong biological evolution argument that horizontal fins are not better than vertical fins for propulsion.  Flatfish with horizontal tails are closely related to the billfish (sailfish, blue marlin, sailfish,…) that are the fastest fish on Earth. Also, some fast sharks frequently swim rolled on their side by up to $60$° in order to take advantage of vertical lift provided by their large vertical dorsal fins. There is clearly no significant evolutionary barrier preventing fish from evolving to swim on their side, so if having tails in a horizontal orientation moving vertically was significantly more efficient, this would be used by at least some fast fish.
For additional information from a biology perspective on this interesting biophysics question, see "Best tail for swimming?" and "Why is there a difference in the rotation of the tail fin in fish compared to marine mammals?".

Such questions are about evolutionary biology, in part, but a central fact about evolution by natural selection is that it allows structure to get gradually adapted to physical facts, and the latter are about physics. In this case the main relevant physical fact is, I think, that pressure increases with depth, and fish are well-adapted to this via their swim bladder (a buoyancy-equalising device). There are then two related matters. First, fish swim mostly horizontally. I suppose this is because the whole ocean environment changes with depth and they have a preferred depth (at any particular time of day). So they are more likely to want to nose around in horizontal turns than vertical ones. This is one reason to prefer horizontal waggling. Another reason is a bit of I guess, but I am guessing that vertical waggling would make it harder to get the buoyancy just right.

It’s to do with their skeletal structure. Most fish have a vertical bone structure, they wag their tails horizontally. 
When I say "vertical" I mean that the bones radiate from the spine vertically, up and down, this means that the natural movement of the spine is constrained in this direction and any flexing of the spine is going to be horizontally, left and right.
Flat fish and mammals have a horizontal skeletal structure - they wag their tails up and down.
Flat fish evolved from fish with a vertical bone structure. If you look at their eyes, one of which migrated from the other side of its body, they are not symmetric. Flat fish live on the sea floor, so their horizontal structure makes sense.
SO the real question is why do fish have a vertical bone structure and land based animals, which evolved from them, do not.
That's a question for biology.

From what I've seen it's that it was evolution from a land animal to an aquatic animal through an amphibious stage, as to why is still a biology question of course.
